Independence of local linear estimators in subsamples from iid draws
Given the following sample $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^n=\{ Y_i, X_i, G_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $Y_i$ and $X_i$ are continuous variables and $G_i$ is a binary grouping variable, with $W_i \sim F$ drawn iid from a joint distribution.
I now want to perform a (local) linear least square estimation in both subsamples to estimate the CEF $E[Y|X=x,G=g]$ for both groups respectively.
So I obtain $\hat m_1(x)$ and $  \hat m_2(x) $. My intuition is that because my draws are iid the two drawn subsamples should be independent from each other and hence the two estimators should also be independent. A friend has challenged this opinion. How can I verify or falsify my claim?
